# Python: argument conversion during string format error /w dictionary/list reads

Tags: python

new to these boards and understand there is protocol and any critique is appreciated. I have begun python programming a few days ago and am trying to play catch-up. The basis of the program is to read a file, convert a specific occurrence of a string into a dictionary of positions within the document. Issues abound, I'll take all responses.

Here is my code:

```
f = open('C:\CodeDoc\Mm9\sampleCpG.txt', 'r')
cpglist = f.read()
def buildcpg(cpg):
    return "\t".join(["%d" % (k) for k in cpg.items()])

lookingFor = 'CG'
i = 0
index = 0
cpgdic = {}
try:
    while i < len(cpglist):
        index = cpglist.index(lookingFor, i)
        i = index + 1
        for index in range(len(cpglist)):
            if index not in cpgdic:
                cpgdic[index] = index
        print (buildcpg(cpgdic))
except ValueError:
    pass
f.close()
```

The cpgdic is supposed to act as a dictionary of the position reference obtained in the index. Each read of index should be entering cpgdic as a new value, and the print (buildcpg(cpgdic)) is my hunch of where the logic fails. I believe(??) it is passing cpgdic into the buildcpg function, where it should be returned as an output of all the positions of 'CG', however the error "TypeError:not all arguments converted during string formatting" shows up. Your turn!

ps. this destroys my 2GB memory; I need to improve with much more reading

Comment: There are actually a number of ways to improve this code. But can you provide a better description of what the ultimate goal is, and some sample data?

Comment: The goal is to compare (union, intersect, subtract, a form of manipulation after converting data from two types of files into similar format dictionaries) a dictionary of positions of targets from a set of files to another which also contains a dictionary of positions of targets from a set of files. This small portion of code is i'd say a 3rd of the total set (optimistic). I'll find a way to include a sample txt, but its just a randomly generated list of nucleotides, "AGTC" about 300 chars in length for now. Ultimately it will be millions in length per file, about 40+ files (memory issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpg.items` is yielding tuples.  As such, `k` is a `tuple` (length 2) and then you're trying to format that as a single integer.

---

As a side note, you'll probably be a bit more memory efficient if you leave off the `[` and `]` in the `join` line.  This will turn your list comprehension to a generator expression which is a bit nicer.  If you're on python2.x, you could use `cpg.iteritems()` instead of `cpg.items()` as well to save a little memory.

---

It also makes little sense to store a dictionary where the keys and the values are the same.  In this case, a simple list is probably more elegant.  I would probably write the code this way:

```
with open('C:\CodeDoc\Mm9\sampleCpG.txt') as fin:
     cpgtxt = fin.read()

indices = [i for i,_ in enumerate(cpgtxt) if cpgtxt[i:i+2] == 'CG']
print '\t'.join(indices)
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> s = "CGFOOCGBARCGBAZ"
>>> indices = [i for i,_ in enumerate(s) if s[i:i+2] == 'CG']
>>> print indices
[0, 5, 10]
```

Note that

```
i for i,_ in enumerate(s)
```

is roughly the same thing as

```
i for i in range(len(s))
```

except that I don't like `range(len(s))` and the former version will work with any iterable -- Not just sequences.

Comment: Alright, so I cannot use tuple for storage in this case. The number of target hits in the docu will be about a hundred thousand, and each is storing a 9 digit number which, supposedly, is getting placed in the dict cpgdic. How can this get passed without use of (tuple)?

Comment: @alexander -- I've edited again to show how I would solve this problem (if I understand it properly).  Of course, this assumes that you have enough memory to read the entire file in in 1 go as well.

Comment: Appreciated, I have tried this new code in a fresh project and as most anticipated events, failed. I removed the _ after [i for i,_] because after running it with the _ present, there was a blank line of output. Removing the _ (i dont know its functionality), the error "too many values to unpack" appeared. Memory related issue? the sample document only contains 300~ characters, and resource monitor spikes from 3-25% instantly but stops once the program errors.

Comment: @alexander -- the `_` is simply a variable which is necessary to prevent the "too many values to unpack"...

Comment: @alexander -- Sorry, original re-write had an index error.  I fixed it in my re-write.

Comment: I ran my sample docu and it worked, thanks for code and knowledge. Yes, the indexing error of only scanning i:i+1 appeared to have needed to be i:i+2. I assume it was not reading anything because it requires +2 to match 'GC' which is 2 char as it scans?

Comment: @alexander -- Yep.  Silly me.